# "Picture" folder basically empty, shows ~47GB usage

Tags: memory, storage, data

I have spent the entire day trying to resolve my 88GB "Other" problem (it is down some now).

I discovered that my "Picture" folder, while basically empty, is ~47GB.

In the folder is an empty photo booth library, and that is it.

What are these phantom 47?

Comment: Do you see this 47GB from quicklook/get info or from the Storage menu in About This Mac?

Comment: Have you emptied your trash? Have you tried going into your Pictures folder, and all sub-folders and right-clicking and choosing *Arrange by name* to move any files into view?

Comment: Use something like [DaisyDisk](http://daisydiskapp.com/) and you'll be able to see exactly where the storage is being used.